# JS: How do I create a 10x10 grid of filled rectangles?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to create 100 filled rectangles in a 10x10 grid. Each of these rectangles is 20px*20px big, and 20px apart from each other. I completely understand the logic behind it, and roughly how to put it into code, but there is one part I can't seem to get my head around; how I make the rectangles appear on the next line after the first 10 have been drawn.

I've got a fiddle here with my current progress: http://jsfiddle.net/z3wsxa8j/

As you can see, they go diagonally. I understand why, because X and Y keep getting +40px added to their coordinates. If I remove the `yvalue += 40;` part, they all go on the same row, obviously. I don't know how I can elegantly make them go on another row after reaching 10 rectangles. I tried using `if/else` statements, so when there's 11 rectangles, make it         `my_context.fillRect(xvalue,40,20,20);` ...
if it's 21 rectangles
`my_context.fillRect(xvalue,80,20,20);` and so on.
But that would A) result in a lot of `if` statements and B) It didn't even work (they printed on the same line, still).

Any hints are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Basic math to the rescue. 10 * 20 = 200. Once you hit 200 width, you reset to left offset to 0 and increase top offset by 20. `var height = 20;
var width = 20;

for (var y = 0; y <= 10; y++) {

for (var x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
    my_context.fillRect((x)*width, (y)*height, width, height);
}
}`

Comment: Here is a working version of what you have: http://jsfiddle.net/z3wsxa8j/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every 10th square, you'll need to do 2 things:

- Increase the "y" value to move down to the next line, and
- Set the "x" value back to 0

Also, you need to make sure you only do 100 boxes and not 101:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    my_context.fillRect(xvalue, yvalue, 20, 20);
    xvalue += 40;
    if ((x+1) % 10 === 0) {
        yvalue += 40;
        xvalue = 0;
    }
}
```

The value of `(x+1) % 10` will be `0` when "x" is 9, 19, 29, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested for loops:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var my_context = canvas.getContext('2d');
my_context.strokeStyle = "white"; // Draws the canvas border
my_context.rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
my_context.stroke();
my_context.fillStyle = "white";

var step = 40;
for (var x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y <= 10; y++) {
        my_context.fillRect(x*step, y*step, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

This code draws the rectangles column by column. Here's a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mereswine/v5LLa90f/)

Comment: Yes this would do it too!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using single if statement and a variable to keep track of number of boxes drawn in a row. When 10 boxes are drawn reset the count and increment the y value.

Updated Fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z3wsxa8j/5/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var my_context = canvas.getContext('2d');
my_context.strokeStyle = "white"; // Draws the canvas border
my_context.rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
my_context.stroke();
my_context.fillStyle = "white";

var xvalue = 0;
var yvalue = 0;
var boxes = 1;
for (var x = 0; x <= 100; x++) {
    if(boxes>10){
        boxes = 1;
        xvalue = 0;
        yvalue += 40;
    }
    boxes++;
    my_context.fillRect(xvalue, yvalue, 20, 20);
    xvalue += 40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically start drawing with one axis 10 rects using an inner loop, and repeating that with `40px` shiftign for the other axis, repeating it 10 times [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/btjkw1du/1/)

NOTE: that in your code you have `(var x = 0; x <= 10; x++)` this will draw 11 rectangles not 10, because you started from 0 and ended at 10, so it should be `(var x = 0; x < 10; x++)` instead of `<=`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var my_context = canvas.getContext('2d');
my_context.strokeStyle = "white"; // Draws the canvas border
my_context.rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
my_context.stroke();
my_context.fillStyle = "white";

var xvalue = 0;
var yvalue = 0;

for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    my_context.fillRect(xvalue, yvalue, 20, 20);
    xvalue += 40;
  }
  xvalue = 0;
  yvalue += 40;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an x and a y loop instead of one big loop:

```
for (var x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y <= 10; y++) {
        my_context.fillRect(x*40, y*40, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you can have a for loop within a for loop, such that you increment each row first, then increment each column.

http://jsfiddle.net/z3wsxa8j/10/

```
var canvasSize = 1000;
var blockSize = 20;
var numBlocks = canvasSize/blockSize;

// Outer loop for each columns
for (var i = 0; i < numBlocks; i++) {
  xvalue = 0;
  yvalue = blockSize*i;

  // Inner loop for the rows
  for (var j = 0; j < numBlocks; j++) {
    my_context.fillRect(xvalue, yvalue, blockSize, blockSize);
    xvalue += blockSize;        
  }
}
```